# Auto Revoke Shared Document Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, document-management

Is it possible to auto revoke permissions on a shared folder or document after a period of time? E.g., if I share "Document A" or "Folder A" with a user for 4 days, after 4 days the users permission should automatically expire.

Answer (score 2):

There is no OOTB feature which will allow you this, but you can create a workflow to achieve this feature.

1. Create extra columns **SharedWith**- person or group  and **Duration** - Number.
2. Create a designer list workflow which assign permission to the user and wait for n days and revoke the user permission.
3. Run the workflow manually when you need to Share the document